# what benefits are there to using a span instead of input

Tags: javascript, html

I've noticed on a couple of websites such as **Facebook**, and **Twitter** that instead of using regular `<input>` fields in their markup, they use a `<span>` and append what the user types onto it using **JavaScript**.

This process is used both, when a user sends direct messages to other users, when a user posts, **and** when a comment is made on a post.

I can't think of any possible reason as to why this would be beneficial to use over the HTML5 native `<input>` tag..

So what are the benefits of using this method? And if there aren't any, **why are they doing it?**

Comment: In a span you can format individual words or letters, or add links, etc. (Like when you tag other users in a comment.)

Comment: @nnnnnn not really useful to them, as the input isn't formatted until it's posted.. :/

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Editable_content How do you add smiles, links, images, etc into a textarea? Answer is you don't ;)

Comment: @epascarello ohh, that would make sense :-) thanks! but even then, facebook doesn't even use the `contenteditable` attribute. It's entirely done in Js.. strange

Comment: Look at Draft.js and it is contenteditable... look at parent elements....

Comment: @Caelan. - When I use Facebook it formats as I type.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

A standard [`input` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input) is limited to plain text input. This works fine for most situations where you are looking for input from the user.

However, both Facebook and Twitter offer something that goes beyond plain text:

[image: Composing example tweet]

As you can see, there is more to it than just plain text: Formatting. Both Facebook and Twitter support inline formatting for special things like mentions and hash tags. In order to format these in a different style, they cannot use an `input` element but have to render the content differently.

Instead, they use a [content-editable element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Editable_content) to allow users to input content while still supporting full formatting capabilities.

Note that while `contenteditable` offers many ways to format stuff, it can also be a nightmare if you’re building something more complex. Medium, who do offer a very powerful and useful text editor, has [written about that topic before](https://medium.engineering/why-contenteditable-is-terrible-122d8a40e480), about how they built their editor, what problems they encountered, and how they tried to get around it.

Answer (score 6):

A `span` or `div` elements can be editable (and provide richer option for the view, like the `@autocomplete` and `#hashtag` for example.

To make a `span` editable you just use the `contenteditable="true"`:

```css
span {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 55px;
  height: 25px;
  font-family: arial;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<span contenteditable="true"></span>
```

The above example only show how to create the element editable (you don't need any javascript for that), but if you want some enhanced options - you can do it only with the editable elements (and not with regular `input` element).

This is an image from the facebook source:
[image]
You can see the `contenteditable="true"` on the 3rd line

Comment: @Caelan., if you are talking about facebook - they do. double check :)

Comment: @Caelan. And if you’re talking about Twitter, they also do ;D

Comment: Oh wait, strange.. They actual do, however, they use it on the parent div, and then append it all onto a child span. Cool :D

Comment: Just updated the answer with a screenshot from facebook's source